# how to start my application when ever mobile restart or turn on

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, bootcompleted

How do i set my application as startup application, so when ever mobile restarts or turned ON, my application starts.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.installedapps22"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

 <application android:icon="@drawable/cherry_icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<activity android:name=".ListInstalledApps" > </activity> 


<activity android:name=".TabsLayoutActivity" />
</application>
   </manifest>
```

**EDIT** Here is my updated code and it is still not working:

Manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.installedapps22"
android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 <application android:icon="@drawable/cherry_icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.app.reciever.BootUpReciever">
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
  <activity android:name=".ListInstalledApps" > </activity> 


  <activity android:name=".TabsLayoutActivity" />
  </application>
 </manifest>
```

BroadcastReciever:

```
 package com.example.installedapps22; 
 public class BootUpReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
 {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);  
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is to set the app as the startup application in your device Create a Class extends BroadCast Reciever

```
public class BootUpReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, ServerPreferenceActivity.class);  
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
}
}
```

Add permissions to manifest file to access bootup receiver

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Register your receiver which extended the `Broadcast receiver` in manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.app.reciever.BootUpReciever">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: add it inside the application tag

Comment: here is what you must replace with, MainActivity.class

Comment: i want to start my applictaion when ever system restrt or Unlock

Comment: you cannot start application on unlock or something, it will start when ever the mobile or tablet will start.

Comment: where have you put the receiver class ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168824/my-application-not-start-on-bootup-mobile   see tis my post

Answer (score 2):

first use permission in manifiest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and declare boot receiver in manifiest

```
<receiver android:name=".BootReciever">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

user receiver to start your mainactivity

```
public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(myIntent);
}

}
```

Comment: have u give complete path of package inside manifiest of bootreceiver

Comment: give me any example application please

Comment: you have to put complete path or boot receiver receiver android:name="com.example.BootReciever where you have made boot receiver class with in package

Answer (score 0):

For your edited code try replacing the following:

```
android:name="com.app.reciever.BootUpReciever
```

with:

```
android:name="com.example.installedapps22.BootUpReciever
```