# my application not start on BootUp mobile

Tags: android

this is my manifiest file below my application not start my application when i turn On mobile i follow this  like [how to start my application when ever mobile restart or turn on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168177/how-to-start-my-application-when-ever-mobile-restart-or-turn-on)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.installedapps22"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />   
 <application android:icon="@drawable/cherry_icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>        
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.app.reciever.BootUpReciever">
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
  <activity android:name=".ListInstalledApps" > </activity> 
  <activity android:name=".TabsLayoutActivity" />
  </application>
 </manifest>
```

Class File

```
package com.example.installedapps22;

public class BootUpReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);  
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions

Answer (score 0):

Check this question of mine, and the answer provided - they are related, and might solve your problem:

- [Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT not received on HoneyComb or ICS (Samsung) devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329810/intent-action-user-present-not-received-on-honeycomb-or-ics-samsung-devices)

Even though the intent used is different, the security issue I describe below is similar.

---

The problem might be that you need to run the application once BEFORE it will respond to the `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent.

This is a security measure.

If you do not run the application, it will not start on boot. Give it a try.

i.e.

1. write app
2. install app
3. RUN APP
4. reboot phone to check if it works

Comment: i want to start my application when ever phone restart or Turn ON

Comment: Your code looks ok, from a quick glance. This is a common problem for new developers - the application needs to be run once when installed... THEN it will listen to the `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent.

Comment: my app willl run i will check it