# Continuously running an app

Tags: android, android-intent

I am making an Android app which is supposed to monitor the other running apps.

The question is, how do I make my app run *continuously* from when i first activate it. It should also start running by itself when I **switch off and reboot** the phone.

Any suggestions on how to ensure this? I am considering using a background thread but I am not convinced this alone will suffice.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17168269/1777090)

Comment: Use [Started Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). However, not good for phone battery.

Answer (score 1):

You should make an android service that running continuusly in background

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm

Answer (score 1):

Well you should try to have an `Service` into your app that could keep track of the other `App's running`

So Every Time the App start's the `Service` Would Start And Accordingly give The Updated to your app regarding the Other App Working

For `Boot Time Start` you Should Try `System BroadCast Receiver`

[You should Really Follow this Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

Create a service to monitor apps in the background.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

To make the app load at boot:

Create a BroadcastReceiver and register it to receive ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED. You also need RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission.

Refer to this:

[Android -Starting Service at Boot Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562734/android-starting-service-at-boot-time)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). But keep in mind that your service can be killed and restarted after a while. 
And you should register a broadcast receiver to listen for [ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) so that you can start the service once the phone booted successfully.